# Middle element in the footer disappear

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I created a footer using `Bootstrap` and I have a little problem on the middle column, in partcular when I reduce the size of the window or try the app on a smartphone I'll get this [result](http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/90/):

[image]

this is my html:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        This is a footer.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center footer-links d-none d-md-block">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Link1</a>
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Link2</a>
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Link3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="requestCulture_RequestCulture_UICulture_Name">
                        Language:
                    </label>

          <select>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.footer {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(152,166,173,.2);
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 19px 30px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    color: #98a6ad;
    left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        This is a footer.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="text-center footer-links d-md-block">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Link1</a>
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Link2</a>
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Link3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <label class="control-label" for="requestCulture_RequestCulture_UICulture_Name">
                        Language:
                    </label>
          <select>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The answer is in this part:

```
  <div class="text-center footer-links d-none d-md-block">
```

`d-none d-md-block` means hide in sizes smaller than mid. 
Just remove `d-none` and your element should stop disappearing.

More information here: [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)

Edit: Added the snippet.

Comment: I removed it and now the middle element overlay the last

Comment: I edited my answer and added the snippet. Is this what you want? If not, can you explain or update your fiddle to show the problem? I also removed col-sm-3 from <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" ... to help with the overlaying of Language and [1].